# simple for loop not working in php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I know this may sound trivial. 
But why is the below code not entering in php?

```
for ($k = "$i"; $k < 0; $k--)
{
//random
}
```

where 'i' is a value from an upper for loop.

Comment: What is the value of `$i`?

Comment: can be anything. It is taken from an upper for loop. I will edit the question. wait.

Comment: Is that for loop right? Do "random" for as long as $k is less than 0, and for reach run subtract 1 from $k. Wouldn't that lead to an endless loop? Yeah it would, just crashed FireFox :P

Comment: @JimL ewwww firefox, there's your problem!

Comment: jimL, how did you test it on firefox ? an addon ?

Comment: @HydraIO I have all major browsers in order to test what I'm doing wrong. Normal weapon of choice is Chrome.

Comment: @tony9099 Just pasted the loop into a netbeans project I had open and ran it on a local dev enviroment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subtracting each time, while checking that it is less than 0.
This will cause an infinite loop, as it will never not be less than 0.

It seems unlikely that you want to do this.  The code you probably wanted is:

```
for ($k = $i; $k >= 0; $k--) {
    //random
}
```

Comment: `$k is being initialized to a string, which has a truth value of 1.` Absolutely not true.

Comment: well, first, not all strings evaluate to `true` (`''` for example), but it is true that `$k` gets initialized to a string. that said, that won't affect loop iteration. as soon as `$k` gets decremented (end of the first iteration), it becomes an integer anyway (assuming `$i` is an integer).

Comment: Right, php will implicitly cast.  I was using the "string is truthy" theory, which would mean the loop never runs.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is that your conditional is backwards if you are using a decrementing counter.  It should presumably be `$k >= 0`.  It may also be a problem that you have quotes around $i, which are unnecessary and problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just this?

```
for ($k = $i; $k >= 0; $k--)
{
//random
}
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed, that your logic will create an infinite loop!  I fixed the code...

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($k = "$i"; $k < 0; $k--)
{
//random
}
```

remove the quotes around `$i` and also give $i a value, so your code looks like the following:

```
$i = 0;
for ($k = $i; $k < 0; $k--)
{
//random
}
```